# SSIS using Script task - Convert XLS to CSV

Tags: c#, ssis

I am using C# script task component to convert XLS to CSV file , my entry point is set to ScriptMain

But I am constantly getting error "Error: Cannot execute script because the script entry point is invalid."

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ST_1feb807359714c80ae0bdd964110df59.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string sourceFile, worksheetName, targetFile;

            sourceFile = "C:\\NewFolder\\Sample.xls"; worksheetName = "sheet1"; targetFile = "C:\\NewFolder\\target.csv";

            convertExcelToCSV(sourceFile, worksheetName, targetFile);

        }
        static void convertExcelToCSV(string sourceFile, string worksheetName, string targetFile)
        {

            string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\" Excel.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

            OleDbConnection conn = null;

            StreamWriter wrtr = null;

            OleDbCommand cmd = null;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = null;

            try
            {

                conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);

                conn.Open();



                cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]", conn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);



                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(dt);



                for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
                {

                    string rowString = "";

                    for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
                    {

                        rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\",";

                    }

                    wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);

                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Done! Your " + sourceFile + " has been converted into " + targetFile + ".");

                Console.WriteLine();

            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());

                Console.ReadLine();

            }

            finally
            {

                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)

                    conn.Close();

                conn.Dispose();

                cmd.Dispose();

                da.Dispose();

                wrtr.Close();

                wrtr.Dispose();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Reading here which looks be very similar to your case, Make sure in the script task's editor, the Script page's Entry Point property is set to ScriptMain. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc15ea13-4b5d-45bd-b6b9-965de144a24c/cannot-execute-script-because-the-script-entry-point-is-invalid .  Or as the guy in this link posted he set his entry point to Main and got it working. Not sure which was the solution as they were both checked.

Comment: MY entry point is set to ScriptMain , not sure why this is happening

Comment: You have an error in your assignment of `strConn` "Excel.0" should be "Excel 8.0"

Comment: I changed entry point to  Main but still I get  "Error: Cannot execute script because the script entry point is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that as you have Main declared as static.

If I used the following inside the body of the partial class `ScriptMain`

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // Look ma, script entry point is invalid!
    }
```

The following error is generated

> SSIS package "Package.dtsx" starting. Error: 0x1 at Script Task:
>   Cannot execute script because the script entry point is invalid. Task
>   failed: Script Task

The entry point is the method named Main that is an instance of the class. *Someone more versed in C# feel free to correct me this* By adding the static specifier, there's only one Main method regardless of how many instances of the ScriptMain class there are.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string sourceFile, worksheetName, targetFile;
        sourceFile = "C:\\NewFolder\\Sample.xls"; 
        worksheetName = "sheet1"; 
        targetFile = "C:\\NewFolder\\target.csv";

        convertExcelToCSV(sourceFile, worksheetName, targetFile);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```