# Filter Excel Data : .Net vs SSIS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a huge amount of data in excel files, with at least 20 columns each file.
I am working with .net (c#), my task is to import rows that met the conditions to insert data into SQL database, for an example, I need to insert only rows with current year (or selected year), also I have column name is 'Full Employee Name' I need to check it if it exists in table Resource Human.

Also other condition is to check if the column name is the same in the SQL table.
I am succeeding to do it with code, but at least 200 lines to do all the possible checks. I read about SSIS (integration service, BI tool), and it looks that can help me to do my task.

My question how doing it? I am stacking with this new concept.

Comment: Usually you load all the contents into the database (a staging table) and then use a stored procedure to do all your validation logic. You may use SSIS to load the excel into the staging table, but there are many other tools also.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing, the idea is I want to customize it without code, maybe mapping can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that choosing the best approach is based on your needs:

- If you are looking to create automated jobs and to perform data import from excel to SQL periodically, i think it is better to go SSIS
- If you are trying to create a small tool that convert an excel file to SQL table, then working with `.NET` is fine
- If you are looking to loop over Excel files with different structure, then you should use `.NET` or [you have to convert files to `.csv` then use SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583954/how-to-configure-input-columns-when-using-dynamic-excel-connection-managers-in-s/54585324#54585324).

Also you can refer to the following Microsoft documentation for more options in importing Excel files to SQL: *(SQL queries, Linked servers, OPENROWSET ...)*

- [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got a working .net solution, and 200 lines of code doesn't sound that bad to me, I wouldn't bother looking into SSIS to replace it.

Comment: the problem that now I am working with 15 column, but I have some Excel files with more than 20 columns, also in the future I need to be able to customize which column imported

Comment: Well Excel is notoriously tricky to work with in SSIS.  I think you're probably still better off keeping it in .net.  Unless you want to first export your Excel files to .csv before importing with SSIS.

Comment: Yes, much better than with Excel.